# how to insert an integer value from a Grid to Sql table?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-binding, tms

I have a `AdvWebGrid` where the 7th column is `DynEdit` where user will enter the value. Now I have to take the entered value and insert it into the SQL table.
For example I have 7 records in the grid, the user will enter some comments for the first three records and save. Now I want to insert/ update the first three comments in the table.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to get the info in the 7th column you could use a datable with the rows you need, the use a sqldataadapter to fill the info into the sql server, i feel this is the best way to do it.

Other way is create a stored procedure in your SQL Server then invoque it from your .net program using `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader`...

Here is an example:

```
Dim val as integer = value you want to insert
Dim comi As New SqlCommand
Dim dr As SqlDataReader
Dim _con as sqlconnection 

_con.ConnectionString = _strcon ' connection string

    comi.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    comi.CommandText = sp_name  ' your stored procedure is sp_name this inserts a value into the table x
    comi.Connection = _con 
    comi.Parameters.AddWithValue("val",val)
    dr = comi.ExecuteReader
    dr.Close()
```

This should do the trick ...

Greetings !